# What is the purpose of the shared with me folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, shared-folders

What is the purpose of the shared with me folder?. It is a public folder, for sharing files with other users.

I was curious because I do not want to place things in there and have them made public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~/Ubuntu One/Shared With Me folder` is a special folder that holds all the folders other Ubuntu One users share with you. If someone shares a folder with you and makes that share writeable, you should be able to read, write and delete files from that folder.

And When you share a folder with someone, they will receive a copy in their `~/Ubuntu One/Shared With Me` folder the next time they synchronize their computer.

More about Ubuntu One : See the [faq](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ).

Also see [Ubuntu One Tutorials](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials).

Comment: Anytime , glad to help :)